# How to change grand total using observer in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to `add some extra amount to Grand total` in **magento**. So in checkout page, order review section will look like this:

[image]
This extra charges will depends on some conditions.

My question is: **How can I change the grand total in checkout page?** For this what I did is: I create a `module`. Please look my code:

**app/code/local/Locwiseship/Customprice/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Locwiseship_Customprice>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </Locwiseship_Customprice>
    </modules>
    
    
    <global>
 
        <events>
        <!-- Création éventuelle du lien de parrainage lors de la commande -->
            <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
                <observers>
                    <set_custom_price_locwiseship>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Locwiseship_Customprice_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Mytotal</class>
                        <method>collect</method>
                                                <method>fetch</method>
                    </set_custom_price_locwiseship>
                </observers>
            </sales_quote_collect_totals_after>             
   
  </events>
        
    </global>

   
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Locwiseship/Customprice/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   Locwiseship
 * @package    Locwiseship_Customprice
 */
class Locwiseship_Customprice_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Mytotal 
    extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCode('mytotal');
    }
    
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);
        
        foreach ($this->_getAddressItems($address) as $item) {
            // These two lines represent whatever logic you're 
            // using to calculate these amounts
            $baseAmt = 10;
            $amt = 10;
        
            // Set the item's total
            $item->setBaseMytotalAmount($baseAmt);
            $item->setMytotalAmount($amt);
        
            // These methods automatically take care of summing 
            // "mytotal_amount" on the quote address
            $this->_addBaseAmount($baseAmt);
            $this->_addAmount($amt);
        }
        return $this;
    }
    
    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        // Naturally, this exists on the quote address because "collect" ran already
        $amt = $address->getMytotalAmount();
        
        if ($amt!=0) {
            $address->addTotal(array(
                    'code' => $this->getCode(),
                    'title' => Mage::helper('Locwiseship_Customprice')->__('My Total'),
                    'value' => $amt
            ));
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**app/etc/modules/Locwiseship_Customprice.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Locwiseship_Customprice>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool>
</Locwiseship_Customprice>
</modules>
</config>
```

That's all my code. But Nothing happened..This is not working..
Am I use the correct approach? How can I make this working? Please help me..
I am using **Magento 1.9.0.1**

Comment: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/ review this blog it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Silksoftware module creator](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/) and it allows you to create new order totals.